# Java XPathFactory thread-safety

Tags: java, xml, xpath, thread-safety

Is javax.xml.XPathFactory.newInstance() thread-safe?

I'm asking because I find the documentation ambiguous for it. [The JDK 5 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFactory.html) don't mention thread-safety at all; in [JDK 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFactory.html) they wrote the following:

> The XPathFactory class is not thread-safe. In other words, it is the
>   application's responsibility to ensure that at most one thread is
>   using a XPathFactory object at any given moment. Implementations are
>   encouraged to mark methods as synchronized to protect themselves from
>   broken clients.

As I understand it, it's not safe to have a singleton implementation for `XPathFactory`, but doing something like this should be safe:

```
XPath xPathEvaluator = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
```

Am I missing something? Does it depend on the actual class that extends it? Do I need to `synchronize` the method that contains the above statement?

Comment: According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathExpression.html XPath expression is also not thread-safe and not reentrant

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> XPath xPathEvaluator = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

That is safe, because every thread gets its own factory (thanks to `newInstance()`). No need to synchronize here.

What you cannot safely do is get the factory just once, and then share it between threads without synchronization, for example as a singleton. The same goes for the XPath instance (`xPathEvaluator`) itself.

Comment: There are many bad things about the JAXP-XPath design. One of them is that XPathFactory.newInstance() is very expensive; another is that you are expected to call it repeatedly in every thread. Another is that you have no way of knowing whether you will get back an XPath 1.0 engine or an XPath 2.0 engine. Ask yourself whether you really want to use this mechanism: if you know what XPath engine you want, there are better ways of loading it.

Comment: Hi Michael, what better ways of loading an XPath engine are there?

Comment: According to Javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFactory.html : `XPathFactory is not re-entrant. While one of the newInstance methods is being invoked, applications may not attempt to recursively invoke a newInstance method, even from the same thread.`, XPathFactory.newInstance() is NOT safe. Synchronize is required. But, I read the source code of XPathFactory, can't figure out which operation is unsafe.

Comment: @aleung: "even from the same thread". So synchronize won't help you here. I am not sure exactly what that warning means, but I would presume that it just says that you should not call newInstance while newInstance is still being executed (not sure how you would even do that, though).

Comment: This answer disagrees with the documentation. The doc clearly says that "While one of the `newInstance` methods is being invoked, applications may not attempt to recursively invoke a newInstance method, even from the same thread." This isn't about whether the instance _returned by_ `newInstance` is thread-safe or not, it's about whether or not the call to `XPathFactory.newInstance()`, which is a _static method_ is thread-safe or not. It's very easy for two threads to call the same static method, @Thilo.

Answer (score 7):

"One of them is that XPathFactory.newInstance() is very expensive;"

True statement! I noticed that for each thread calling newInstance(), jaxp.properties must be located on the classpath and read in:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:160)
        - locked <0x0000000968dec028> (a sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:208)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getEntry(URLJarFile.java:107)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:114)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:132)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
        at javax.xml.xpath.SecuritySupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.xml.xpath.SecuritySupport.getURLInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryFinder._newFactory(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryFinder.newFactory(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

ZipFile makes a native call (to zlib I believe) and decompresses the jar, which needs disk IO and processor bound zip decompression. In this instance we had 1400+ threads waiting on that lock.