# How do I use XPath in a thread-safe and efficient manner?

Tags: java, multithreading, xpath

(A similar question has been asked here, [Java XPathFactory thread-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110514/java-xpathfactory-thread-safety), but the given answer is incorrect because it ignores the fact that the documentation states that `XPathFactory.newInstance()` isn't thread-safe.)

From the [XPathFactory Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFactory.html), we have:

> The XPathFactory class is not thread-safe. In other words, it is the
>   application's responsibility to ensure that at most one thread is
>   using a XPathFactory object at any given moment. Implementations are
>   encouraged to mark methods as synchronized to protect themselves from
>   broken clients.
>
> XPathFactory is not re-entrant. While one of the newInstance methods
>   is being invoked, applications may not attempt to recursively invoke a
>   newInstance method, even from the same thread.

**So from the above quote, I take it that `XPathFactory.newInstance()` (a static method) should not be called concurrently. It is not thread-safe.**

The factory returns XPath objects, which has this [XPath Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html):

> An XPath object is not thread-safe and not reentrant. In other words,
>   it is the application's responsibility to make sure that one XPath
>   object is not used from more than one thread at any given time, and
>   while the evaluate method is invoked, applications may not recursively
>   call the evaluate method.

**From the above quote, I take it that `XPath.evaluate` and `XPathExpression.evaluate` should not be called concurrently. They are not thread-safe.**

Normally when I'm dealing with classes that aren't thread-safe I just use local variables, but because `XPathFactory.newInstance()` isn't thread-safe, and it's a static method, I'm not sure how to use it safely and efficiently. I guess I could synchronize calls to `newInstance`, but I worry about performance because my application is an XML message routing application. (In my smoke tests of `newInstance` it takes ~0.4 milliseconds.)

I can't find any examples of use Java XPath in a thread-safe manner, and I'm not confident I know how to use XPath in a thread-safe but efficient manner. I also have the constraint that I need to use XPath inside a singleton (specifically an [Apache Camel Processor](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/user-manual/modules/ROOT/pages/processor.adoc)).

Comment: FYI, the closest I found to an example is Apache Camel's [XPathBuilder](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/builder/xml/XPathBuilder.java), which states that "This implementation is thread safe by using thread locals and pooling to allow concurrency", but the implementation seems tightly-coupled to Camel and some parts are over my head.

Comment: Re, "I could synchronize calls to `newInstance`, but I worry about performance." Have you _measured_ the performance? Step 1 (for me, anyway) is always, do something easy that works. Step 2 is, evaluate whether it works _well enough_. If the answer in step 2 is "yes", then the problem is solved.

Comment: `javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance()` creates a new _factory_. How many distinct XPath factories does your application need?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood reentrancy. XPath is not threadsafe at all and furthermore, the _same_ thread cannot call evaluate during an evaluation.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I have not measured performance, and I know I should. But just for this question I'm making an assumption that calls to [`newInstance` are expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15301904/201891). As for how many distinct factories I need, I'm processing SOAP XML messages in a pipeline using CXF components deployed to Tomcat, so there is a configurable thread-pool. I suppose to achieve maximum concurrency, I would need factories and expressions equal to the thread-pool, but that's getting into a complicated potential answer to this question that I'm not confident about.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I assume your comment is directed at Solomon and not me, the OP, because that's exactly what this question is about: XPath is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I take it that `XPathFactory.newInstance()` (a static method) should not be called concurrently. It is not thread-safe.

That documentation could be interpreted differently: thread-safety and reentrancy are distinct attributes, so it is possible for `XPathFactory.newInstance()` to be thread-safe yet non-reentrant. The word *recursively* seems key; but the sentence structure is difficult to parse. Without reviewing the code in minute detail, synchronization around any `newInstance` calls seems the only safe way to use them. Note that Java 9 added the [`newDefaultInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFactory.html#newDefaultInstance--) method, which appears trivially thread-safe.

> I take it that `XPath.evaluate` and `XPathExpression.evaluate` should not be called concurrently. They are not thread-safe.

Agreed. The documentation clearly states these methods are neither thread-safe nor reentrant.

Comment: It's useful to note that thread-safety and  re-entrantcy are distinct attributes, but I don't understand how we could "recursively invoke a newInstance" method, especially given that it's a static method. The full quote says "While one of the newInstance methods is being invoked, applications may not attempt to recursively invoke a newInstance method, _even from the same thread_" (emphasis mine). Given that the exception proves the rule, "even from the same thread" also means "from any thread", and given that this is a _static method_, we can't use it concurrently.

Comment: I've revised my answer. The documentation is ambiguous and the source code is convoluted. Java 9 seems to have addressed the problem with a new method.

Answer (score 3):

You could abandon the JAXP/DOM world and move to Saxon, where multithreading is much more carefully incorporated into the API design:

- Unlike the DOM, the Saxon native tree implementations are thread-safe once document building is complete. You also get XPath 3.1 as a bonus.
- An XPathCompiler is thread-safe once configured using its setter methods
- An XPathExpression (created by compiling an expression using an XPathCompiler) is thread-safe (it can be executed concurrently in multiple threads)
- An XPathSelector (formed by loading an XPathExpression) is not thread-safe; it should only be evaluated once.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, Michael. I've read similar suggestions before along the lines of "It's a shame this (JAXP/DOM) is popular because there are better alternatives." I will investigate this and put it in my back pocket for now because I'm invested in figuring out how the provided implementation works.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation seems to focus on objects, not newInstance calls.  Here are the parts you’ve quoted;  I have added some emphasis:

> The XPathFactory class is not thread-safe. In other words, it is the application's responsibility to ensure that at most one thread is using **a XPathFactory object** at any given moment.

And:

> **An XPath object** is not thread-safe and not reentrant.

Notice that it is referring to *existing objects.*  XPathFactory.newInstance is a static method;  it does not operate on an existing XPathFactory object.  At the moment it is called, there is no object to potentially share between threads.

The documentation is stating that non-static methods of existing XPath and XPathFactory objects are not thread-safe.  It is not saying that you can’t create them in different threads, only that you can’t use an object in different threads (unless you protect that usage with synchronization or Locks).

**Update:** It’s possible that “While one of the newInstance methods is being invoked, applications may not attempt to recursively invoke a newInstance method” may refer to concurrent XPathFactory.newInstance calls, but I take the presence of “recursively” to mean that a particular newInstance call may not invoke another call to newInstance.  This theoretically can happen if you invoke the [three-argument newInstance method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFactory.html#newInstance(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.ClassLoader)) with name of a factory class which itself attempts to call newInstance.

Comment: You seem to be skipping over the part that says "_While one of the newInstance methods is being invoked, applications may not attempt to recursively invoke a newInstance method, even from the same thread._" This seems to explicitly state that these `newInstance` static methods are not thread-safe.

Comment: Good point.  Of interest is the word “recursively” in that paragraph.  I take that to mean that the factory specified by the `factoryClassName` parameter cannot invoke any other XPathFactory.newInstance methods.  But, just to be safe, you can guard all calls to XPathFactory.newInstance with a common Lock or synchronization on a common object.